# How can I get the amount of days between two dates?

Tags: python, mysql

I got a python script, which is supposed to fetch data of my mysql table (contains a date) and then it should print out the amount of days between today´s date and the date of my mysql table.

I already tried substracting the two dates, but this wouldn´t work. So I tried substracting today´s date and my birthday, which worked. So I think the problem is the mysql date.

```
import datetime
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="",
  database='appointments'
)

eventDate = mydb.cursor()
eventDate.execute('SELECT event_date FROM appointdatetitle')
Date = eventDate.fetchall()

tdelta = datetime.timedelta(days=7)
today = datetime.date.today()
eday = Date
till_eday = eday - today
print(till_eday.days)
```

Comment: What type of column is `event_date`? Also, what does 'this wouldn't work' mean? Are you getting an error? If so please include the full stack trace.

Comment: Why not do this in mysql query itself. like this:  SELECT event_date, datediff(event_date, NOW()) days FROM appointdatetitle

Comment: the type of event_date in mysql is DATE. If you mean this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date = eventDate.fetchall()` [fetchall](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.fetchall) actually fetches a tuple of tuples
e.g.
`(('abcd',), ('efgh',))`

You would want to get the Date by looping over the list and getting the elements. e.g.

```
for d in Date:
    #This will contain the date you need
    print(d[0])
```

Or you can directly access an element by doing say `Date[0][0]`

After update from OP, this is what can be done!
OP can use https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html to use the
`from dateutil.relativedelta import *` to increment the month!

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import *

Date = [(datetime.date(2019, 4, 24),)]

#Extract actual datetime object from Date variable
date_obj = Date[0][0]

#Increment month by 1 since January starts from 0
date_obj += relativedelta(months=1)

today = datetime.date.today()

#Using datetime from above
eday = date_obj
till_eday = eday - today
print(till_eday.days)
```

The output will be `23`

Comment: Your text says 'list of tuples', but you example shows a tuple of tuples, picky I know, but it is something that might send a beginner down the wrong path.

Comment: Updated! How did I miss that! Please check if it is good, and consider upvoting if it is :)

Comment: Well I think it's likely to be the answer but until the OP includes the actual error in the question, we'll never know!

Comment: This is the error I get, when I try to run it, as I mentioned it in my question:     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\RaspberryPiCalendar\Calendar.py", line 29, in <module>
    till_eday = eday - today
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'datetime.date'
[Finished in 0.128s]

Comment: This is the output: [(datetime.date(2019, 4, 24),)]

Comment: And did you try using `Date[0][0]` as I mentioned! See my updated answer

Comment: It kind of works now. But it´s the wrong result. The result should be 23 because in this situation the Date is - 24th of May and today is the 1st of May.

Comment: The date you provided is 24th April `2019-04-24` and not 24th May `2019-05-24`, could you check again? @MaxBauer

Comment: I think I have to go more into detail now. This python script is part of a calendar project with a raspberry pi. I wrote a website which runs on apache on the pi and it includes a calendar (done with Js - in this case january is month 0 (January-December = 0-11)) where you click on a date and then you can insert an appointment onto this date. The calendar and the website work just fine and now I want the python script to get the data out of the mysql and display it on a monitor attached to the pi.

Comment: I think the question here was you not being able to extract Date out the pymysql which you are now able to do, anything around it something which I might not have expertise of, also in case if january is month 0, you could always increment the month of the date you fetched! Or adjust the dates accordingly! Unfortunately `datetime` module doesn't give an easy way to increment months

Comment: @MaxBauer That extra info is not really relevant to the question as stated. if you are not getting the answer that you are looking for you need to improve your question. Try including a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .

Comment: If I understood it right. I have to increment the month by 1 and then I´ll get the right amount of days?

Comment: Yes you are correct! Will you be able to do it by yourself! I think since this next part is out of the scope of the original question, you can give it a shot! @MaxBauer

Comment: @MaxBauer I have updated the code to add a month to your date as well. It would be great if you could matk the answer as accepted if it helped you :)